# upload a Excel file without header in Grid View (already defined column names) in asp .net C#, each time it show error when reaches at dt.Rows.Add()

Tags: asp.net

here the code which i am using to import excel to grid view.. Each time getting error at dt.Rows.Add()

here the error "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.Couldn't store  in SUPPLY DATE Column.  Expected type is DateTime."

in .aspx page i don't defined any column with datetime

DataTable dtExl = conUpLoad.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

```
                string getExcelSheetName = dtExl.Rows[0]["Table_Name"].ToString();

                OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + getExcelSheetName + "]", conUpLoad);
                OleDbDataAdapter ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand);
                DataSet ExcelDataSet = new DataSet();
                ExcelAdapter.Fill(ExcelDataSet);

                //conUpLoad.Close();



                // Clearing the grid ::::::::::::::::::::::
                ViewState["dt"] = null;
                GridView1.DataSource = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
                GridView1.DataBind();

                // ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
                DataTable dt = ExcelDataSet.Tables[0];

                int i = 0;
                if (ExcelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    String DINumber = ExcelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    String PartNo = ExcelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    String DeliveryDt = Convert.ToDateTime(ExcelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString()).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                    String Location = ExcelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();
                    String Qty = ExcelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][7].ToString();
                    String PartyCode = ExcelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][10].ToString();

                    dt.Rows.Add(DINumber, PartNo, DeliveryDt, Location, Qty, PartyCode);

                    ViewState["dt"] = dt;
                    GridView1.DataSource = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
                    GridView1.DataBind();


                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    GridView1.DataSource = null;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
```

Comment: `DeliveryDt` is probably empty or not convertible to a DateTime. Debug your code and see what values it hold.

Comment: DeliveryDt has value with proper format

Comment: Here you can see the screenshot  https://prnt.sc/imym84